# How to use placeholders in dynamic camel-kafka endpoint?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

I am using a dynamic endpoint to send messages to Kafka.

```
   private static final String OUTPUT_TOPIC = "OutputTopic";
   ...

   private void setOutputTopic(Exchange exchange) {
       //some other code
       exchange.setProperty(OUTPUT_TOPIC,"MyKafkaTopic");
   }
   ...
   @Override
   public void configure() {    
        from("direct:someEndpoint")
                .process(this::setOutputTopic)
                ...
                .toD("kafka:${exchangeProperty." + OUTPUT_TOPIC + "}");             
  }
```

With Camel version 3.4.x everything worked fine. After migration to Camel version 3.14.x several tests started to fail due to optimization in [KafkaSendDynamicAware](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/components/camel-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/kafka/KafkaSendDynamicAware.java#L70) that creates kafka endpoint with URI that contains unresolved placeholders and Camel test facilities does not work as before:

```
@MockEndpointsAndSkip("kafka:MyKafkaTopic")
...

@EndpointInject("mock:kafka:MyKafkaTopic")
private MockEndpoint mockedMyKafkaTopic;
```

Could you suggest the proper way how to test dynamic Kafka endpoint in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the dynamic topic name using the property placeholder syntax `{{some.property}}`:

```java
@Override
public void configure() {    
     from("direct:someEndpoint")
             .process(this::setOutputTopic)
             // ...
             .toD("kafka:{{" + OUTPUT_TOPIC + "}}");             
}
```

Comment: The problem is that Camel will create Kafka endpoint with endpoint URI: `kafka://$%7BexchangeProperty.OutputTopic%7D` which is not what I would expect in tests. And dynamically resolved topic name will be placed into `KafkaConstants.OVERRIDE_TOPIC` header and checked during message sending in [KafkaProducer](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/components/camel-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/kafka/KafkaProducer.java#L288).